# Chrome: Strange Tiling Behavior

Tags: xmonad

sorry for being a n00b with Haskell, but every time I open Chromium on my XMonad Arch Linux machine I get this weird side window with chromium's underlying data.

Look at the image here if it helps:

[image]

I want, when opening chromium, to not show this strange side window. I do not care if chromium is floating or full screen or anything, I just want this weird window gone!

Sorry for being new to xmonad!!

Here is a snippet from my `xmonad.hs` file:

```
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers (composeOne, isFullscreen, isDialog,  doFullFloat, doCenterFloat)

myManageHook = composeAll. concat $
            [ [ className =? c --> doCenterFloat| c <- floats]
            , [ resource =? r --> doIgnore | r <- ignore]
            , [ resource =? "gecko" --> doF (W.shift "net") ]
            , [ isFullscreen --> doFullFloat]
            , [ isDialog --> doCenterFloat]]
where floats = ["chromium", "Vlc"]
       ignore = []
```

Comment: Starting Chromium from the terminal is sure unwieldy. Maybe define a keybind [like this](https://github.com/Minoru/dotfiles/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs#L100)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Chromium from the command line you could install dmenu and call it via dmenu. The reason for the underlying data is that you start it via the terminal, so the terminal will stay there because it's kinda "hosting" the process of Chromium.

Import Dmenu in your xmonad configuration:

```
import XMonad.Util.Dmenu
```

And install the package [dmenu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dmenu).

You can then call it with your mod Key and "P" or define a key mapping in your config. In my case I press "Windows"-Key and "P" and then dmenu opens and I type "Chromium".